# What regular expression should I use for this sample?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a command output like this

```
hdisk10                  128000         200B75Y4191001707210790003IBMfcp
hdisk11                  128000         200B75Y4191001807210790003IBMfcp
hdisk13                  128000         200B75Y4191001A07210790003IBMfcp
hdisk14                  128000         200B75Y4191001B07210790003IBMfcp
hdisk15                  128000         200B75Y4191001C07210790003IBMfcp
hdisk16                  128000         200B75Y4191001D07210790003IBMfcp
hdisk17                  128000         200B75Y4191001E07210790003IBMfcp
hdisk18                  128000         200B75Y4191001F07210790003IBMfcp
hdisk19                  128000         200B75Y4191002007210790003IBMfcp
```

I want only the first column containing the `hdisk` names. I want to delete the everything after the `hdiskXX` in every line. `XX` can be 1-3 digits, mostly 2 digits.

I tried the following regular expression

**Find :** `hdisk[0-9][0-9].*`

**Replace :** : `hdisk[0-9][0-9]`

But the resultant string is like `hdisk[0-9][0-9]` instead of `hdisk10`. Why is it not interpreting `[0-9]` as a regular expression and simply treating it literally?

What regular expression should I use here to accomplish what I want?

I am trying this on Notepad++ which supports regex search and replace.

Comment: Yeah, you need to capture.  You can't specify ranges in the replacement, that doesn't make any sense.  "Replace with a digit [0-9]" -- is it just suppose to make one up? ;)

Comment: I don't use notepad++, but you can achieve what you want using `awk` with this simple command: `awk '{print $1}' infile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use capturing groups. Try seaching for `(hdisk[0-9]+).*` and replace it with `\1`.

The `\1` means *"whatever was found within the first parenthesis"*.

(Reference: http://ozansafi.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/notepad-regular-expression-usage/)

Comment: Thanks, it helped :). Can you point me to some good docs describing this capturing mechanism?

Comment: You can have a look at this article: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html but there are dozens of them on the Internet :)

Comment: @Stacker, added a reference :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's very general but should work. Find `\s+\d+\s+200B.*` and replace with empty string. I am not sure if you can use \d and + in notepad++...Check for yourself

Comment: Can you kindly explain what your regex does?

Comment: It finds positive number of spaces (1 or more) followed by positive number of digits followed again by positive number of spaces followed by a string that starts with 200B followed by anything. It works in this case, but I can imagine situations that are more complex and then aioobe's approach seems more reasonable.